# JSONPath: How to get path if value is present in array?

Tags: jsonpath

This is the sample object

```
{
 "names": [
   "David",
   "Steve",
   "Wilson"
]
...<other properties>
}
```

I wanted to write query in JSON path to check if `"Steve"` is present in `"name"` property of above object and need to return the path if the value exists.

Ref: https://github.com/kawamuray/jsonpath#path-syntax

Comment: I'm going to assume it's `$.names[*]?(@ == "Steve")`. If it is, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @Samathingamajig, I tried your solution on https://jsonpath.com/, Although it says "No match". Can you please try there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This path works: `$.names[?(@ == "Steve")]`

[image]

Comment: thanks @Samathingamajig, this worked, can you also help me in: 
if the value present then the query returns 1 and if not present, return 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following expression on [jsonpath.com](https://jsonpath.com)

```
$.names[?(@ == 'Steve')]
```

It returns an array with `'Steve'` as a string if it exists.